# Image Manipulation PHP

Tags: php, image, image-processing

I am creating facebook app in which I have user image as background image and have a default cap image which user can move around. After user has placed the overlayed image(a hat) over the right place he clicks save
This is where I am struck and like to know how can I save the background + where user placed hat as single image, if this makes sense. I donot know how to approach this whether these image can be saved as one or do i get positions where the other image was placed
If someone can suggest

Answer (score 2):

You can simply place the hat image using the [GD libraries](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) which are available on most web hosts. The specific method that will be interesting to you is [imagecopymerge](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php).

Alternatively, you might consider simply storing the coordinates in your database and then reassembling the image in HTML, assuming you don't need to send the image anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

if you use jquery, check out position(). This will get the hat position (top, left values) in relation to the parent (which should be the backgroun image).

On dragging the hat, update some hidden inputs with the values from position(). Now when you submit the form you have top/left positions which you can use as X/Y positions in GD or imagick to make one single image, or store in a database so you can render the hat in the correct place next time it loads the page up

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the placement coordinates using javascript, and then transfer them to PHP. Since i don't have any specifics about your code i can only give you hints:

1) Get the hat image placement coordinates

2) Compute the OFFSET of the hat vs the head

3) Send that to PHP with all info you might need to process the request

4) Use GD to imagecopy the hat onto the head's picture and save it

5) Show or output a link to the image...

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)
For reference [Check](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/annotating/) how Imagemagick Overlay of image onto another image is done